# How to make a submenu display only if the <li> is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I need help achieving a certain effect for mobile.  I want the `submenu` to display only if the parent `<li>` is clicked and it should slide from right to left just like this [one](http://www.indochino.com/) (view on mobile)

here is my current [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajg614v/4/)

```
var flag = 100;
$('#button').click(
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({
            left: flag
        }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html(flag ? 'Close' : 'Menu');
        });
        flag = flag ? 0 : 100;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS and jquery changes.

**CSS**

```
#menu ul ul {
  display:none;
  padding:10px;    
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
 var effect = 'slide';
 var options = { direction: 'right' };
 var duration = 700;
 $("#menu ul > li a").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(effect, options, duration);
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajg614v/6/)

**NOTE:** You have to add `Jquery UI` for this kind of animation.

Comment: I apply the changes in my `current div.site` but when i click the parent li the `menu` is close any idea about this

Comment: mmm..not sure. If you reproduce it in fiddle i can check.

Comment: I found the problem I have `value` in my `a` `tag` that is the reason why it close because it go to the other page thank's for your quick reply...